# Question related to Baire category and generic set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem on Baire category and generic set (also known as set that is of 2nd category)

> Let $\{x_j\}_{j = i}^\infty$ be enumeration of the rational numbers in $\mathbb{R}$, and consider the sets $$U_n = \bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty (x_j - \frac{1}{n2^j},x_j + \frac{1}{n2^j}) $$ and $$U = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n$$
>   Show that $U$ is generic but has Lebesgue measure zero.

Well since generic set is where the complement of it is of 1st category, I would want to figure what the complement is, but I am a bit confused about the union of the set in general.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each $U_n$ is open because it's a union of open intervals, and is dense because it contains $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore $E_n=U_n^c$ is closed and nowhere dense. This implies that $E=U^c=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, hence is of the first category.

On the other hand,
$$ m(U_n)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^{j-1}}=\frac{2}{n} $$
and since $U\subset U_n$ for all $n$, this implies that $m(U)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $U_n$ contains all rationals, $U_n$ are dense open for all $n$. It implies that $U$ is generic.

However, $m(U_n)\leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j-1}n}\rightarrow 0$.
Thus $m(U)=0$.

This example shows that the topology and measure are very different in talking about "nothing"